# Convert object to JSON Array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following object being returned. I am counting a list of names by reading from a json file and storing the results in a new object.

```
{
    ted: 501,
    jeff: 40,
    tony: 90
}
```

The following function creates an object with the names as properties and the count as their values.

```
function countNames(json){

    var count = {};

    for (var i = 0, j = json.length; i < j; i++) {

       if (count[json[i].name]) {
          count[json[i].name]++;
       }
       else {
          count[json[i].name] = 1;
       } 
    }  

    return count;
}
```

I need to create an array of objects that generate a result like this.

```
[
    {
        name: 'ted',
        total: 501
    },
    {
        name: 'jeff',
        total: 40
    }
    {
        name: 'tony',
        total: 90
    }           
]
```

I am not sure what the best approach and most efficient way of achieving this is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's `city`? Can't you already take what you've done with `countNames` and just add each to an array instead?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been the name property. I corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand how your code example relates to the question, but this turns the data in the first format into the last format:

```
var output = Object.keys(input).map(function(key) {
  return {
    name: key,
    count: input[key]
  }
});
```

it uses functional programming style, which usually leads to cleaner code.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jusebo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Note to OP: Keep in mind [`Object.Keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is ECMA 5.1, so <IE9 will throw up on you. (Though I suppose `for...in` has the same limitation) :: Also, @joews: SO has code snippets now, no need to reference an off-site JSBin.

Comment: @BradChristie Thanks for the compatibility note. I prefer JSBin where there is no visual output, or when I think the OP may want to play about with the code.

Answer (score 6):

Consider this following **Javascript** snippet:

```
for (var item in obj) {
    result.push({
        name: item,
        total: obj[item]
    });
}
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqu46sbn/)

Output:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"ted",
      "total":501
   },
   {  
      "name":"jeff",
      "total":40
   },
   {  
      "name":"tony",
      "total":90
   }
]
```

Comment: I like this solution better because it doesn't require ECMA 5.1, yet the performance appears to be nearly the same as using the Object.keys() method. I think the for-in look is ECMA 3 or earlier (?).